# How can a Java program list all partitions and get the free space of them on Linux?

Tags: java, linux, file

I want the name of the partition with their total space, used space and free space for the Linux system using java program.

I am getting correct value in case of Windows system but in Linux I am getting only one drive information:

Here is what I have tried so far.

```
public class DiskSpace {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    FileSystemView fsv = FileSystemView.getFileSystemView();
    File[] drives = File.listRoots();
    if (drives != null && drives.length > 0) {
        for (File aDrive : drives) {
            System.out.println("Drive Letter: " + aDrive);
            System.out.println("\tType: " + fsv.getSystemTypeDescription(aDrive));
            System.out.println("\tTotal space: " + aDrive.getTotalSpace());
            System.out.println("\tFree space: " + aDrive.getFreeSpace());
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Linux does not have drives. It has [mounted](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mount_%28computing%29) [file systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system). So on Linux your question does not make any sense. Run commands `df` and `mount` in a terminal to understand your mounted file systems.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "only one drive information"?

Comment: I mean it displays root files information. Pro grammatically how can i get all files information

Answer (score 6):

There are no drive letters on Linux. If you want to know which partitions there are, and where they are mounted, read `/proc/mounts`. When you have a mount point (2nd column in /proc/mounts), use `new File(mountpoint).getTotalSpace()` to get the total space.

Comment: @Basile: If he wants to write a 'generic' java program, reading `/proc/mounts` will be much easier than calling `df` or `mount` from java - seems his program is intended to 'replace' df. Of course, he'll run into trouble with `/proc/mounts` if he wants to use his program on any other kind of unix-ish system.

Comment: I agree with you. My suggestion of running `df` and  `mount` in a terminal is first for the OP to understand something. Then, if he really needs the information programmatically, he could use `/proc/mounts` but he might need to avoid special cases like `/proc`, `systemd`, `binfmt_misc`, `udev`, `devpts`, `fusectl` and `pstore` pseudo-filesystems. So it could be more difficult than what you propose.

Comment: Agree. Sometimes a nice version of "get a clue" is the best answer ;)

Answer (score 4):

Linux, Unix, and Unix-like systems have one filesystem with one root within which there may be multiple mount points at which partitions containing Unix filesystems, partial or complete, may be mounted -- non-Unix filesystems may also be mounted with the appropriate software available to handle the transformations necessary, but the unified, single-root filesystem model remains.

If the `FileSystemView` class you are using is from the [`javax.swing.filechooser`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/filechooser/FileSystemView.html) package, don't expect too much:

> FileSystemView is JFileChooser's gateway to the file system. Since the JDK1.1 File API doesn't allow access to such information as root partitions, file type information, or hidden file bits, this class is designed to intuit as much OS-specific file system information as possible.
>
> Java Licensees may want to provide a different implementation of FileSystemView to better handle a given operating system.

That second paragraph is key.

Java's virtual machine implementation is meant to abstract away the very kind of platform specific things you want in this case. To be successful, you will need to write or find native call wrapper classes for the native system API of each platform you will support. "High-level" abstractions like the `FileSystemView` class are unlikely to be complete or reliable in providing the information you need.

Answer (score 2):

This is a code snippet to display name mounted external media only.

```
String OS = System.getProperty("os.name");
if(OS.equals("Linux"))
{
    String s = "";
    Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
    int n=0;
    Process ps = rt.exec("ls /run/media/Rancho");// Write your UserName, mine is Rancho

    InputStream in = ps.getInputStream();
    while((n = in.read())!=-1)
    {
        char ch = (char) n;
        s+ = ch;
    }
    System.out.println(s);  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm late to the party here, but I wrote a class that just does its job. What it does is reading the /proc/mounts file, parses it into the Block Device (like /dev/sda), Mount Point, file system Type and its mount options. If you don't need the additional things that I wrote, you can exclude it, but for the project that I am working on, I wanted to include it, like if the current user can write or read into/from the current mount point.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class UnixPartition {

    private final String block, mount, fsType, mntOptions;
    private final long totalSpace, freeSpace, usableSpace;
    private final File root;

    protected UnixPartition(String block, String mount, String fsType, String mountOptions, long totalSpace, long freeSpace, long usableSpace, File root) {
        this.block = block;
        this.mount = mount;
        this.fsType = fsType;
        this.mntOptions = mountOptions;
        this.totalSpace = totalSpace;
        this.freeSpace = freeSpace;
        this.usableSpace = usableSpace;
        this.root = root;
    }

    public String getBlock() {
        return block;
    }

    public String getMount() {
        return mount;
    }

    public String getFilesystemType() {
        return fsType;
    }

    public long getTotalSpace() {
        return totalSpace;
    }

    public long getFreeSpace() {
        return freeSpace;
    }

    public long getUsableSpace() {
        return usableSpace;
    }

    public String getMountOptions() {
        return mntOptions;
    }

    public boolean canCurrentUserWrite() {
        return root.canWrite();
    }

    public boolean canCurrentUserRead() {
        return root.canRead();
    }

    private String getLineSeparator(String contents) {
        char[] chars = contents.toCharArray();

        long r = 0;
        long n = 0;

        for (char c : chars) {
            if (c == '\r')
                r++;

            if (c == '\n')
                n++;
        }

        if (r == n)
            return "\r\n";
        else if (r >= 1 && n == 0)
            return "\r";
        else if (n >= 1 && r == 0)
            return "\n";
        else
            return "";
    }

    public static List<UnixPartition> getPartitions(boolean filterSpecials) throws IOException {
        String contents = new String(FileUtil.read("/proc/mounts"));
        String[] lines = contents.split(getLineSeparator(contents));

        List<UnixPartition> partitions = new ArrayList<>();

        for (String line : lines) {
            StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line, " ");
            String blk = tokenizer.nextToken(),
                    mnt = tokenizer.nextToken(),
                    type = tokenizer.nextToken(),
                    opt = tokenizer.nextToken();

            if (filterSpecials) {
                if ((blk.contains("proc") || mnt.contains("proc") || type.contains("proc")) ||
                        (blk.contains("systemd") || mnt.contains("systemd") || type.contains("systemd")) ||
                        (blk.contains("binmft_misc") || mnt.contains("binmft_misc") || type.contains("binmft_misc")) ||
                        (blk.contains("udev") || mnt.contains("udev") || type.contains("udev")) ||
                        (blk.contains("devpts") || mnt.contains("devpts") || type.contains("devpts")) ||
                        (blk.contains("fuse") || mnt.contains("fuse") || type.contains("fuse")) ||
                        (blk.contains("pstore") || mnt.contains("pstore") || type.contains("pstore")) ||
                        type.contains("tmp"))
                    continue;

                if (blk.contains("none"))
                    continue;
            }

            File root = new File(mnt);

            partitions.add(new UnixPartition(blk, mnt, type, opt,
                    root.getTotalSpace(), root.getFreeSpace(), root.getUsableSpace(), root));
        }

        return partitions;
    }

}
```

Edit: You might want to filter out the special mount types yourself, since I just used them from another answer here.